# Pulling of docker image from a registry fails

Tags: linux, docker, docker-registry, lxc, device-mapper

Would love some help about an issue. When I was trying to download an image form the repository it failed and I could see the following errors in the log file. This is the syslog which I received

```
Jan  4 10:22:05 <hostname> kernel: device-mapper: thin: commit failed: error = -22
Jan  4 10:22:05 <hostname> kernel: device-mapper: thin: switching pool to read-only mode
Jan  4 10:22:05 <hostname> kernel: bio: create slab <bio-2> at 2
Jan  4 10:22:06 <hostname> kernel: device-mapper: btree spine: node_check failed: blocknr 0 != wanted 27706
Jan  4 10:22:06 <hostname> kernel: device-mapper: block manager: btree_node validator check failed for block 27706
Jan  4 10:22:06 <hostname> kernel: device-mapper: thin: process_bio_read_only: dm_thin_find_block() failed: error = -15
Jan  4 10:22:06 <hostname> kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-3, logical block 8388592
Jan  4 10:22:06 <hostname> kernel: device-mapper: btree spine: node_check failed: blocknr 0 != wanted 27706
Jan  4 10:22:06 <hostname> kernel: device-mapper: block manager: btree_node validator check failed for block 27706
Jan  4 10:22:06 <hostname> kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-3, logical block 8388592
Jan  4 10:22:06 <hostname> kernel: device-mapper: btree spine: node_check failed: blocknr 0 != wanted 27706
Jan  4 10:22:06 <hostname> kernel: device-mapper: block manager: btree_node validator check failed for block 27706
Jan  4 10:22:06 <hostname> kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-3, logical block 8388606
Jan  4 10:22:06 <hostname> kernel: device-mapper: btree spine: node_check failed: blocknr 0 != wanted 27706
Jan  4 10:22:06 <hostname> kernel: device-mapper: block manager: btree_node     validator check failed for block 27706
Jan  4 10:22:06 <hostname> kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-3, logical block 8388606
Jan  4 10:22:07 <hostname> kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-3, logical block 0x
Jan  4 10:22:07 <hostname> kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-3, logical block 0
Jan  4 10:22:07 <hostname> kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-3, logical block 1
Jan  4 10:22:07 <hostname> kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-3, logical block 8388607
Jan  4 10:22:07 <hostname> kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-3, logical block 8388607
Jan  4 10:22:07 <hostname> kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-3, logical block 8388607
Jan  4 10:22:08 <hostname> kernel: device-mapper: space map common: dm_tm_shadow_block() failed
Jan  4 10:22:08 <hostname> kernel: device-mapper: space map common: dm_tm_shadow_block() failed
Jan  4 10:22:08 <hostname> kernel: device-mapper: space map metadata: unable to allocate new metadata block
Jan  4 10:22:08 <hostname> kernel: device-mapper: thin: Deletion of thin device 66 failed.
Jan  4 10:22:10 <hostname> kernel: device-mapper: table: 252:3: thin: Couldn't open thin internal device
Jan  4 10:22:10 <hostname> kernel: device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
Jan  4 10:22:10 <hostname> kernel: device-mapper: thin: Deletion of thin device 66 failed.
Jan  4 10:22:10 <hostname> kernel: device-mapper: table: 252:3: thin: Couldn't open thin internal device
```

This is the logs from docker

```
time="2017-01-04T10:22:08Z" level=error msg="Error from V2 registry: read /dev/mapper/docker-252:0-263231-3690474eb5b4b26fdfbd89c6e159e8cc376ca76ef48032a30fa6aafd56337880: input/output error"
Error: image ims:<image_tag> not found
time="2017-01-04T10:22:09Z" level=info msg="-job pull(<iamge>, <image_tag>) = ERR (1)"
time="2017-01-04T10:22:09Z" level=info msg="POST /v1.18/containers/create?name=<container_name>"
time="2017-01-04T10:22:09Z" level=info msg="+job create(<container_name>)"No such image: <iamge>:<image_tag> (tag: <image_tag>)
time="2017-01-04T10:22:09Z" level=info msg="-job create(<container_name>) = ERR (1)"
time="2017-01-04T10:22:09Z" level=error msg="Handler for POST /containers/create returned error: No such image: <iamge>:<image_tag> (tag: <image_tag>)"
time="2017-01-04T10:22:09Z" level=error msg="HTTP Error: statusCode=404
No such image: <iamge>:<image_tag> (tag: <image_tag>)"
time="2017-01-04T10:22:09Z" level=info msg="POST /v1.18/images/create?fromImage=<image_url>"
time="2017-01-04T10:22:09Z" level=info msg="+job pull(<iamge>, <image_tag>)"
time="2017-01-04T10:22:09Z" level=info msg="+job resolve_repository(<iamge>)"
time="2017-01-04T10:22:09Z" level=info msg="-job resolve_repository(<iamge>) = OK (0)"
time="2017-01-04T10:22:09Z" level=info msg="+job trust_key_check(/xyz)"
time="2017-01-04T10:22:09Z" level=info msg="-job trust_key_check(/xyz) = OK (0)"
time="2017-01-04T10:22:10Z" level=error msg="Error from V2 registry: Driver devicemapper failed to create image rootfs 3690474eb5b4b26fdfbd89c6e159e8cc376ca76ef48032a30fa6aafd56337880: device 3690474eb5b4b26fdfbd89c6e159e8cc376ca76ef48032a30fa6aafd56337880 already exists”
```

Please let me know if any other data is needed. I have the backup of the old docker lib folder.

Comment: Can you provide the download (pull?) -command?

Comment: Yes, please write full `docker pull <component>` and error log.

Comment: Also if you're using your own `Dockerfile` please add it to the OP

Comment: Hello Folks Sorry for the delayed response.! The docker pull command is plain and simple. `docker pull image_name` .

Comment: @ReynierPM I dont think I would be able to paste the Docker file. Could you please help me if there is anything particular you are looking for.I would be able to paste excerpts from there.

Comment: @Gaurav I am trying to find where the problem is coming from but if you said this is only caused running a simple command then the Dockerfile isn't needed. Which Docker version are you using?

Comment: @ReynierPM We are using Docker version 1.6.1

Comment: @Gaurav that's really old is there any chance you can upgrade to the latest one and try?

Comment: @ReynierPM The issue got fixed once I removed the /var/lib/docker and restarted the docker service. And I am not even able to reproduce the issue.